# Angular ng build -p AoT issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I have an issue when execute the command ng build -prod in my project, i actually expend a lot of time reading about the error show in the console:

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Calling function 'RequesthuellaModule', function calls are not
>   supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference
>   to an exported function, resolving symbol TallerModule in
>   /Users/mac/generator/boilerplate-webangular2/src/app/modules/taller/taller.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol TallerModule in
>   /Users/mac/generator/boilerplate-webangular2/src/app/modules/taller/taller.module.ts

All anwsers i found tell that use some lambda function, but i haven`t in my code. i put the source of the files i use:

**Library requesthuella.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HuellaService } from './../serviceS/huella.service';
import { RequestHuellaOpciones } from './../models/RequestHuellaOpciones';
import { RequestHuellaComponent } from './requesthuella.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // Pipes.
        // Directives.
    ],
    exports: [
        // Pipes.
        // Directives.
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule
    ]
 })
 export class RequesthuellaModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: RequesthuellaModule,
        providers: [HuellaService, RequestHuellaComponent]
      };
  }


    public static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
          ngModule: RequesthuellaModule,
          providers: [HuellaService, RequestHuellaComponent]
      };
    }

}
```

**taller.module.ts**

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
  import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';
  import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
  import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
  import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';
  import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
  import { DirectivesModule} from 'app/directives/directives.module';
  import {DataTableModule} from 'angular2-datatable';
  import { RequesthuellaModule, HuellaService, RequestHuellaComponent } from '@oc/requesthuella-library';

  import { TallerRoutingModule } from './taller-routing.module';
  import { TallerComponent } from './taller.component';
  import { TallerFormComponent } from './taller-form.component';

  import { CentrosService } from './services/centros.service';
  import { TallerModalComponent } from './modals/taller-modal/taller-modal.component';

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      TallerRoutingModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      OrderModule,
      NgxPaginationModule,
      TooltipModule.forRoot(),
      BlockUIModule,
      ModalModule.forRoot(),
      DirectivesModule,
      DataTableModule,
      RequesthuellaModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [TallerComponent, TallerFormComponent, TallerModalComponent, RequestHuellaComponent],
    providers: [
      CentrosService,
      HuellaService
    ],
    entryComponents: [TallerModalComponent],
  })
  export class TallerModule { }
```

i dont know why the error appears, by the way if i build only with ng build it work like a charm, only cause the issue when add the -prod argument.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was. a version of the templete im using for the library scaffolding i just update it and also, configure the file tsconfig.ts.

The code is right, just dependencies obsoletes and mal configuration.